# Add a scrolling transition between components svelte

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I have this svelte component that renders a dynamic component, what I want to do is: when the "this" on svelte:component changes I want to run a "scrolling-like" transition, so the current pages moves to the top of the screen and the next page comes from the bottom at the same time, so I came up with the fly animation reversed on in and out, but there is a problem: the first in transition succeeds, the first page does come from the bottom of the page, but when the component changes, only the out animation displays, the current page goes to the top of the screen, but the next in animation doesnt display, the next component just appears after a short time, it seems like the out animation is conflicting with the next in animation because they run at the same time, but that's the behavior I want, how to achieve this ? Here is the code for my component:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import type { SvelteComponent } from 'svelte';
  import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
  import Layout from './lib/components/layout.svelte';
  import { page } from './lib/stores';
  import { tick } from 'svelte';

  let pages = Object.entries(import.meta.glob('./lib/pages/*.svelte')).map(
    async ([path, page]) => ({
      path,
      component: (await page() as any).default as typeof SvelteComponent,
    })
  );

  page.subscribe((_) => pages = pages);
</script>

<Layout>
  {#await Promise.all(pages) then pages}
    {#each pages as { path, component }}
      {#if path === $page.path}
        <div class="page"
          in:fly={{ y: window.innerHeight, duration: 1000 }}
          out:fly={{ y: -window.innerHeight, duration: 1000 }}>
          <div id="header">
            <h1>{$page.title}</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="content">
            <svelte:component this={component} />
          </div>
        </div>
      {/if}
    {/each}
  {/await}
</Layout>

<style>
  .page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1.5fr 8.5fr;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(29, 215, 103);
  }

  #content {
    margin: 5%;
    font-size: x-large;
  }
</style>
```